# Función en Python devuelve doble resultado

Tags: python, funciones, float

estoy haciendo esta función en Python:

```
def calcula_rentabilidad_acciones(Accion_1: str, Accion_2: str, Accion_3: str, inversion_1:float, inversion_2: float, inversion_3: float, rentabilidad_1: float,           rentabilidad_2: float, rentabilidad_3: float, tasa_cambio: float):
    valor_ac_1 = float(inversion_1 * rentabilidad_1 * tasa_cambio)
    valor_ac_2 = float(inversion_2 * rentabilidad_2 * tasa_cambio)
    valor_ac_3 = float(inversion_3 * rentabilidad_3 * tasa_cambio)
    suma: float = valor_ac_1 + valor_ac_2 + valor_ac_3
        return f"Su rentabilidad en el mes para la {Accion_1} fue: ${round(valor_ac_1)}, {Accion_2} fue: ${round(valor_ac_2)}, {Accion_3} fue: ${round(valor_ac_3)} y su rentabilidad total fue {round(suma)}"
    print(calcula_rentabilidad_acciones("RET_ACC_1", "RET_ACC_2","RET_ACC_3", 345.65, 657.98, 643.23, -15, 12, 23, 3200.54))
```

Para lograr este resultado:

```
Su rentabilidad en el mes para la RET_ACC_1 fue: $-165940.0, RET_ACC_2 fue: $252706.96, RET_ACC_3 fue: $473497.17 y su rentabilidad total fue 560264.13
```

Por medio de la salida:

```
print(calcula_rentabilidad_acciones("RET_ACC_1", "RET_ACC_2", "RET_ACC_3", 345.65, 657.98, 643.23, -15, 12, 23, 3200.54).
```

Sin embargo el resultado que me da es:

```
Su rentabilidad en el mes para la RET_ACC_1 fue: $-16594000, RET_ACC_2 fue: $25270696, RET_ACC_3 fue: $47349717 y su rentabilidad total fue 56026413
Su rentabilidad en el mes para la RET_ACC_1 fue: $-16594000, RET_ACC_2 fue: $25270696, RET_ACC_3 fue: $47349717 y su rentabilidad total fue 56026413
```

Es decir que en la terminal me muestra una sola vez pero al hacer el test se está imprimiendo dos veces.

Para acercarme a los valores que me piden le agregué la función **round** pero no me imprime con punto decimal. ¿Alguien que me pueda guiar por favor?

Comment: en primer lugar tu codigo funciona correctamente y para especificar un decimal a la funcion `round()` le tienes que pasar un segundo parámetro `round(numero,3)` donde el `3` indica la cantidad de decimales

Comment: ¿Ya intentaste sacar el `print` que está dentro de la función? Y lo que dice Christian es cierto a `round` le tienes que colocar la cantidad de decimales que quieres mostrar.

Answer (score 0):

El código funciona correctamente una vez corregido el sangrado de las líneas:

```
def calcula_rentabilidad_acciones(Accion_1: str, Accion_2: str, Accion_3: str, inversion_1:float, inversion_2: float, inversion_3: float, rentabilidad_1: float,           rentabilidad_2: float, rentabilidad_3: float, tasa_cambio: float):
    valor_ac_1 = float(inversion_1 * rentabilidad_1 * tasa_cambio)
    valor_ac_2 = float(inversion_2 * rentabilidad_2 * tasa_cambio)
    valor_ac_3 = float(inversion_3 * rentabilidad_3 * tasa_cambio)
    suma: float = valor_ac_1 + valor_ac_2 + valor_ac_3

    return f"Su rentabilidad en el mes para la {Accion_1} fue: ${round(valor_ac_1,2)}, {Accion_2} fue: ${round(valor_ac_2, 2)}, {Accion_3} fue: ${round(valor_ac_3, 2)} y su rentabilidad total fue {round(suma, 2)}"


print(calcula_rentabilidad_acciones("RET_ACC_1", "RET_ACC_2","RET_ACC_3", 345.65, 657.98, 643.23, -15, 12, 23, 3200.54))
```

También agregue el parámetro "2" a la función `round` para especificar el número de decimales deseados.

Resultado:

```
Su rentabilidad en el mes para la RET_ACC_1 fue: $-16593999.77, RET_ACC_2 fue: $25270695.71, RET_ACC_3 fue: $47349716.92 y su rentabilidad total fue 56026412.86
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda!!!! Sin embargo al agregar el parámetro 2 a la función round, el resultado varía como puedes observar en el enunciado; dejando la función round sin parámetros me da los valores que me piden pero no me pone los decimales...

Comment: @YesidBarrera. Mi cálculo da -16593999.77, que redondeado queda en -16594000. Los resultados son iguales